# Как добавлять слэш команды к дискорд боту

Tags: discord.py

Просмотрев несколько сайтов, включая оф.документацию дискорда - у меня было несколько вариантов.

1 - json.
Я пробовал добавить слэш команду, через библиотеку `requests`. Но получив ни ошибки, ни результата, я забросил json

2- `discord-py-slash-command`. аналогичный результат с json.

После окончательного провала, я пошел на `stackoverflow`, ну и сейчас задаю вопрос.

Коды:

Json -

```
import requests

url='https://discord.com/api/v8/applications/#id_application/guilds/#guild_id/commands'

json={
    "name":"test",
    "description":"Super test",
}   

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bot #токен"
}

r= requests.post(url, headers= headers, json=json)
```

discord-py-slash-command(IN COGS) -

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import cog_ext, SlashContext


class Slash1(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @cog_ext.cog_slash(name="ping")
    async def ping(self, ctx: SlashContext):
        await ctx.send(content="Pong!")

def setup(bot:commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(Slash1(bot))
```

Comment: посмотрите `py-cord`

Comment: Ребят, разобрались как добавить свою / команду в дискорд?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы был добавлен часто повторяющийся запрос в строку с командами. Как можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

После обновления кода слэш команд надо подождать какое-то время, так как срабатывает рейт лимит и необходимо перепригласить бота на сервер уже с включёнными слэш-командами, включить их можно на сайте https://discord.com/developers/